# How can i get the google calendar feeds on my website

Tags: google-calendar-api, feed

I have the public google calendar and i am trying to get the feed so that i can show the upcoming events on my sidebar with event name and event date.

I am not able to find it.

I got this link

http://www.ducttapemarketing.com/blog/2007/03/17/a-google-calendar-list-of-events-feed-on-your-web-site/

But i am not able to create feedburner account.

Is there any other easy way for this

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- the google calendar embeds (go to calendar details, "Embed This Calendar"). There you can customise to show the agenda view (e.g. this provides an embed which is similar to https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=6vv7tct80gv5tblahm5sg0vsos%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/Paris (click on agenda))
- roll your own from google's json feed (or ical feed, or xml feed, or html feed), which can also be found from the calendar details. note that you can add parameters to specify the format, such as json: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/6vv7tct80gv5tblahm5sg0vsos@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script.